# JobScheduler run job at most once every time the conditions are met

Tags: android

NOTE: THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE, PLEASE READ THE QUESTION

I want to run a job every time the device is Charging & ON WIFI. This job has to run at most once every time these conditions are met.
This means that if I leave the phone charging overnight with wifi ON the job should not repeat itself. 
Only when I unplug and replug the job is allowed to execute again. Same goes for when I turn wifi off and on.

```
    builder.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED)
            .setRequiresCharging(true)
            //.setPeriodic(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10))
            .setPersisted(true)
```

Job scheduler provides methods like setPeriodic but that will run my job every X amount of time. Not really what I want.
The job is not critical, I don't need it to be executed right away after the conditions are met, and I'm also OK with it not executing at all sometimes (meaning it's ok for it not to be run when conditions are met for a short period of time)

Is it possible to achieve this using job scheduler? The documentation on this is pretty scare.

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution to your problem? I need the same functionality and seems like it is impossible...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not using `setPeriodic`, then your job would only run once when your other constraints are set. However, your requirements mean you need to schedule a new job when you leave those conditions - `JobScheduler` does not offer that API, nor does Android offer any API that does that that also works with [Android 8.0's Background Execution Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html) (with the exception of continuously running a foreground service).

Comment: Thank you! I tried to achieve the desired result by calling onJobFinished(paremeters, needsReshchedule = true) instead of set periodic. But I understand this only runs the job again with the set backoff strategy (linear or exponential).
So does this mean that my use case is simply not possible in Android?

Comment: Anything you could do, including waiting for `onStopJob` (which is going to be called after ~10 minutes anyways), is going to be much worse for the overall system health than just doing it periodically every few hours.

Comment: You could also consider just scheduling a new job when your `onStartJob` fires that uses `setMinimumLatency` - that'll ensure that the next run is at least that far into the future. That would avoid the periodic jobs firing even when your other constraints aren't met.

Comment: I really like your last suggestion! I will try that and see how it goes